# Android Studio bottom button is not showing when run the program but it shows in design view

Tags: android, xml

I'm writing an Android lab and somehow my bottom button and text enter part are not showing. I'm using Linear Layout. it shows in the XML file design mode but doesn't show when running the program. Can someone help me find out what the problem is?

I tried to add a pic of what my design page and program run pic but it's not letting me, when I run the program I can see the two strings that I added to an array, but just not see the button and plain text at the bottom

here is my code, I have my java file code list below the xml code:

```xml
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="684dp" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="send" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/typehere"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Type here"
    android:textColor="#9C9B9B" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/receive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="receive" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout> 
</ListView>
```

my activity

```java
public class ChatRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    EditText input;
    Button receive;
    Button send;
    ArrayList<String> items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        input = findViewById(R.id.typehere);
        receive = findViewById(R.id.receive);
        send = findViewById(R.id.send);

        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("I'm sending");
        items.add("I'm receiving");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); // see the list of result of adaptor

        receive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = input.getText().toString();
                addMessage(text);
                input.setText("");
            }
        });

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = input.getText().toString();
                addMessage(text);
                input.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void addMessage(String message){
        items.add(message);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after straggling in the display, I found the height for ListView is longer than my screenview, so I edit the xml to

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
   
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:visibility="visible">
```

and the rest of the code didn't change
I guess for others that has same issue try to shorter the listview's height

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout` and can add `android:layout_above` attribute to your `ListView`

Example code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llBottomLayout"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:visibility="visible">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```